# Move a table in the article before its declaration

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, positioning, article

Hello I wrote 3 macros for creating a table of content I add within the article. `\startMyTable`, `\inMyTable`, `\createMyTable` their names suggests what they do.

So when I write:

```
Hello
\startMyTable 
Hello2

\inMyTable{FIRST}
\inMyTable{SECOND}

Hello3
\createMyTable
Hello4
```

It creates something like this:

```
Hello
Hello2
Hello3
 --------
|  FIRST |
 --------
| SECOND |
 --------
Hello4
```

Is there I way to move the table at a certain point of the article (e.g. at the beginning of it)? I see this requires like a pre-compilation of the latex syntax but I have no clue about how to do it and what to search. Do you have any tip?

I post the code I was suggested to use for creating tables like these:

```
\newcommand\startMyTable{\def\MyTable{\begin{tabular}{|l|}}}

\newcommand\inMyTable[1]{%
   \edef\MyTable{%
   \expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\MyTable#1\\}}}

\newcommand\createMyTable{\begin{center}\MyTable\end{tabular}\end{center}}
```

Comment: The typical way of moving stuff to a point *ahead* of where it is defined (e.g., table of contents info) is to perform a 2-pass compilation in which the first pass writes the data to the `aux` file and the 2nd pass reads the `aux` file and uses that data anywhere in the document, even if at a place before its original definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\startMyTable{%
\immediate\write\@auxout{\unexpanded{%
  \gdef\MyTable{}}}}

\newcommand\inMyTable[1]{%
\immediate\write\@auxout{\unexpanded{%
   \xdef\MyTable{%
   \expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\MyTable#1\\}}}}}

\newcommand\createMyTable{%
  \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|}\ifx\MyTable\@undefined \ldots\else\MyTable\fi\end{tabular}
\end{center}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\createMyTable

\section{zzz}


Hello
\startMyTable 
Hello2

\inMyTable{FIRST}
\inMyTable{SECOND}

Hello3

Hello4

\end{document}
```

Like all such things, takes two runs (you get ... in the first run)